# Copy image file from /storage/emulated/0/Pictures to another directory in cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ngcordova

I am building a small hybrid app. I used the [cordova-base64-to-gallery plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-base64-to-gallery) to covert a base64 image from a cropped image (using Croppie) to a png file which is then stored in the Picture's folder, in the phone's image gallery. Saving the base64 string to an image works well so far and I can see it in the image gallery. But my problem is how to copy this image which returns the **path** as **/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/img_imageFile.png** to the *cordova.file.dataDirectory* using [ngCordova file plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/).

Here is my angularjs code

```
// Beginning the conversion process...
cordova.base64ToGallery(base64ImageString, {
                                             prefix : 'img_',
                                             mediaScanner : true
                                           },

     function (path) {
         //path = /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/img_imageFile.png
         //console.log(path);
         var sourceDirectory = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
         var sourceFileName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, path.length);

         $cordovaFile.copyFile(sourceDirectory, sourceFileName,  cordova.file.dataDirectory).then(function (success) {
             //$scope.profileImage = cordova.file.dataDirectory + sourceFileName;
             alert("Request Successfully Completed");
         }, function (error) {
             console.dir(error);
             alert("Error: " + error); // returns Error: [object Object]
         });

     }, function (err) {
             console.error(err);                             
     });
 });
```

I am working with Onsen2, Cordova6.2.0, cordova-plugin-file 4.2.0, android 6

I am still quite new and will appreciate any solutions to my problem or better approach. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! After hours and hours of experimenting and googling, I found another plugin ([Cordova saveImageGallery on Github](https://github.com/agomezmoron/cordova-save-image-gallery)) which is actually an enhancement of the previous one I was using. 
Here is my code for those in need though you can get more from the plugin's page

```
var params = {data: base64ImageString, prefix: 'img_', format: 'JPG', quality: 80, mediaScanner: true};
window.imageSaver.saveBase64Image(params,

   function (filePath) {
      //console.log('File saved on ' + filePath) = file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/img_imageFile.png
      var sourceDirectory = filePath.substring(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      var sourceFileName = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, filePath.length);

      $cordovaFile.copyFile(sourceDirectory, sourceFileName,  cordova.file.dataDirectory).then(function (success) {
          alert("Request Successfully Completed");
      }, function (error) {
         console.dir(error);
         alert("Error: " + error);
      });
   },
   function (msg) {
      console.error(msg);
   }
);
```

Remember to install the plugin first. Thanks to anyone who tried looking into this :)